# What is the relation of natural rights to human rights ?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-law, rights, human-rights

Assuming that there are natural rights and human rights, are they co-extensive - so that to have (all) natural rights is to have (all) human rights and vice versa? Is there any difference in their contents - in what they are rights to or from - and is the basis of natural rights, their justificatory ground, that same as that of human rights ?

Answer (score 2):

Natural rights encompasses human rights. Humans are, after all, a component of nature. I would add the diagram, but couldn't do it now, as I am having problems attaching the pictures.

To get back to the topic, natural rights encompasses human rights. You could consider natural right as a universal set, and human rights as its subset. Hope this answer helps.